# ADFS server timeouts issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, adfs, time-out

We are using the sharepoint authentication as ADFS. Now, I have a problem that ADFS goes timeout  within an hour. This happens even if the user is doing something in the page.

I think, ideally this should not happen, rt ? It should timeout only after the page goes idle for certain time. If something is done in the page, then the idle time should be reset, rt?

Am I missing something ?